# Remove last character of a text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

How may I remove the last character of a text file in the shell without an unwanted final nextline?

Can you believe I tried more than 3 hours...

Actually, only this works :

```
printf '%s\n' '$' 's/.$//' wq | ex $2
```

However, the suppressed comma is replaced by a "next line". I tried to modify this code but nothing works... How may I remove the last character of a text file in the shell without an unwanted final nextline?

**EDIT :**

My CSV is written like that :

url1,

---

url1,url2,

---

url1,url2,url3,

---

url1,url2,url3,;reference

---

So, the problem is the ,; I need to delete the , before to write : ;reference

Now I am thinking I could also, at the end, search all ",;" and replace it by ";"..

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [ask])

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: `sed '$ s/.$//' /the/file` with remove the last char from a file. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html